# Calling same template from 2 different layout files Magento2

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to keep the same templates phtml files in different modules and call them in different layout files?

Eg:  i have a **template1.phtml** in Vendor/Module1/view/front/templates/template1.phtml

where template1.phtml is called from Module1's layout file.

I need to keep the same content of template1 in **template2.phtml**

and can I call that template with Modules two's layout file?

If I did so, template2 is not getting called!!

**UPDATE:**

**\Vendor\Module1\view\frontend\layout\catalogsearch_result_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock class="Vendor\Module1\Block\Navigation" before="-" name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module1::layer/view.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

view.phtml in templates/layer folder

** IN Vendor\Module2\view\frontend\layout\m_result_index.xml**

```
 <referenceBlock class="Vendor\Module1\Block\Navigation" before="-" name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module1::layer/view.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Here, calling the same view.phtml in this layout file.

But it's not getting called. (I need to get the filters in the product page, which is coming from 1st modules layout file, but not from a 2nd layout file)

Comment: at which place you have declared xml code for template2.phtml // or please show your code for declaration of template1.phtml and template2.phtml filie

Comment: Please post your `layout.xml` file

Comment: Updated both the modules layout file

Comment: Any changes to be done or update on the layout file @Ankit?

Comment: Not sure @SachinS Let me check & revert ASAP

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep below code for your second xml file,

Instead of call **`Vendor\Module1`** you have to keep **`Vendor_Module1`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock class="Vendor\Module1\Block\Navigation" before="-" name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module1::layer/view.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Remove var and clear cache try again.

Comment: Sorry @Rakesh, i have updated the code, i have replaced the _ with / while changing the Vendor/Module...If  Vendor_Module1 is the only change, then thats what i have used and cleared all cache too!

Comment: any update @Rakesh ?

Answer (score 0):

Take the reference of **vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_configure.xml**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

or you can also do

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Custom\Module\Block\Posts\ViewPosts" name="custom_module.posts.view" template="posts/view.phtml" />
            <block class="Custom\Module\Block\ListIndex" name="custom_module_mylist_block" template="mylist.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Make sure you have **correct** template path, otherwise it will be not called.

I have checked & it's working fine.